# Automatically Forwarding EMails using Google App Scrpiting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I use gmail and I am trying to learn Javascript.  I know there may be other ways but I want to figure this one out mostly to learn where my thought process is wrong.  My goal is to learn JavaScript and Google App Script.

I mark e-mails in gmail with a specific label, and I eventually want to forward all of those e-mails to a specific person.  The person changes depending on who is doing the work.  What I am hoping for:

- Script goes to a Google sheet to look up the columns, A client name, B email to be forwarded to, C current label and D label to archive it to.  (examples, A: Fire Club, B: example@fireclub.co, C: inbox/FireClub, D: Archive/FireClub
- Forward e-mail, attachments changing the subject to "Client Name - Old Subject" (i.e. from "Burn it" to "Fire Club - Burn it"
- Message is then removes from initial label (column C) and labeled with its new label (column D)

Below is what I have, again, I know I can clean some of it up (changing columnB to be recipient for example), but I can't get the core to work yet.  When I try to run the below, it will run through about half of the messages in the label and then return "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forward' of undefined myFunction @ Code.js:21" this is the line that actually sends the message.

```html
        threads[i].getMessages()[i].forward(recipient, {subject: subject}); // Sends e-mail
```

I appreciate your help.  I have included the whole of the code below in case it isn't just the line above.  Thank you!

```html
function myFunction() {

  var sheetID = 'ID'; //Edit this to your sheet ID.
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  let rowNum = 6; //Need to make this match to labels, but good enough for a POC
  var values = sheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  let columnA = values[rowNum][0]; // get column A - Client Name
  let columnB = values[rowNum][1]; // get column B - email
  let columnC = values[rowNum][2]; // get column C - label
  let columnD = values[rowNum][3]; // get column D - archive

// Grab E-Mails to send
  var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(columnC);
  var archive = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(columnD);
  var threads = labels.getThreads();
  var length = threads.length;
  let recipient = columnB;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let subject = columnA + ' - ' + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject();
    threads[i].getMessages()[i].forward(recipient, {subject: subject}); // Sends e-mail
    Logger.log("Thread ID: " + threads[i].getId() + " Message Sent: " + columnA + " - " + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()) // Changes subject to add Client name in front
    archive.addToThread(threads[i]); // Adds the label that is shown in dolumn D of the spreadsheet
    labels.removeFromThread(threads[i]); // removes the inbox label
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the same index `i` to get the thread and a message in it, but the thread might have a different number of messages. For example, the 10th thread may have only 5 messages, so you'll get `undefined` if you try to access the 10th message of this thread.

If you're trying to get the first message of the thread (for example, if it has only one message), then you can use `getMessages()[0]`.

If you want to forward all messages, you need to loop through the messages retrieved by `getMessages()`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  let subject = columnA + ' - ' + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject();
  let messages =  threads[i].getMessages();
  for (let j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
    messages[j].forward(recipient, {subject: subject}); // Sends e-mail
    Logger.log("Thread ID: " + threads[i].getId() + " Message Sent: " + columnA + " - " + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject()) // Changes subject to add Client name in front
    archive.addToThread(threads[i]); // Adds the label that is shown in dolumn D of the spreadsheet
    labels.removeFromThread(threads[i]); // removes the inbox label
  }
}
```

Depending on the case, you can also include an IF statement to only forward messages that fulfill a specific condition.

Comment: Threads are a group of messages and can have multiple messages within a single thread.  So if I am calling on thread #4, but that only has one message, it is trying to send message 4 of thread 4 and returns undefined.  That is an interesting problem to have to work around, I think the message within a thread will usually be the first one, but may not always be.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I've added a snippet showing how to loop through the messages, and you can also add an IF to check for a specific condition before forwarding the message.

Comment: Thank you for that snippet.  I was slowly building on it, but couldn't get the core to work as intended.  You solved the problem I was having, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad the snippet was helpful. In this case, consider accepting this as the answer to the question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID");
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let recipient = r[1];
    let labels = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(r[2]);
    let archive = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(r[3]);
    let threads = labels.getThreads();
    threads.forEach(t => {
      let subject = `${r[0]} - ${t.getFirstMessageSubject()}`;
      t.getMessages().forEach(m => {
        m.forward(r[1], { subject: subject });
        archive.addToThread(t);
        labels.removeFromThread(t);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This seems heavily optimized.  I hope you can help me understand various parts.  

Is 'vs' finding the full range of data in the spreadsheet?

Is forEach((r, i) defining each of the columns in the sheet as an array?

I don't understand what forEach(t is defining exactly, or what 't' and 'm' are calling on.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: vs is taking the data form line 2 to the bottom of data.  If you read the code carefully and refer to this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) you should be able to figure it out.